# Batch Script to edit input file for a program

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to write a script that will edit an input file with varying parameters and run a program that uses that input file. I would like to do 200+ runs. I've written code that does one run successfully, but does not work when I try to put the same code in a FOR loop.

This is the code for one iteration that works fine

```
@echo
set "file=Current.hot"
set /a isoLine#ToSearch=67
set /a sourceLine#ToSearch=68

set sourceList[0]=SourceTerm = 300
set isoList[0]=SourceTermName = a
set fileList[0]=a

set sourceList[1]=SourceTerm = 30
set isoList[1]=SourceTermName = ab
set fileList[1]=ab

set sourceList[2]=SourceTerm = 3
set isoList[2]=SourceTermName = ac
set fileList[2]=ac

set sourceList[3]=SourceTerm = .3
set isoList[3]=SourceTermName = ad
set fileList[3]=ad


(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET "Line=%%b"
    IF %%a equ %isoLine#ToSearch% SET "Line=!isoList[3]!"
    IF %%a equ %sourceLine#ToSearch% SET "Line=!sourceList[3]!"
    ECHO !Line!
    ENDLOCAL
))>"%file%.new"
TYPE "%file%.new"
MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3
start Hotspot303.exe
timeout /t 4
ren Current.out !fileList[3]!.txt
```

Now here is the same code with my attempt to make it into a loop.

```
@echo off 

set "file=Current.hot"
set /a isoLine#ToSearch=67
set /a sourceLine#ToSearch=68

set sourceList[0]=SourceTerm = 300
set isoList[0]=SourceTermName = a
set fileList[0]=a

set sourceList[1]=SourceTerm = 30
set isoList[1]=SourceTermName = ab
set fileList[1]=ab

set sourceList[2]=SourceTerm = 3
set isoList[2]=SourceTermName = ac
set fileList[2]=ac

set sourceList[3]=SourceTerm = .3
set isoList[3]=SourceTermName = ad
set fileList[3]=ad

(for /l %%k in (0,1,3 ) do (    
    (FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        SET "Line=%%b"
        IF %%a equ %isoLine#ToSearch% SET "Line=!isoList[%%k]!"
        IF %%a equ %sourceLine#ToSearch% SET "Line=!sourceList[%%k]!"
        ECHO !Line!
        ENDLOCAL
    ))>"%file%.new"
    TYPE "%file%.new"
    MOVE "%file%.new" "%file%"


    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3
    start Hotspot303.exe
    timeout /t 4
    ren Current.out !fileList[%%k]!.txt
))
```

Any thoughts on why this stops working when placed in a loop?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `echo on` to see where your code stop. and put `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3` between double quoute => `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3"`

Comment: Maybe that first  `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3"`? Use `pushd` and `popd` command pair instead. As an alternative, omit it at all and use `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3\Hotspot303.exe"`, see http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: @SachaDee good catch! Damned closing parenthesis in `Program Files (x86)`!

Comment: There is no `cd` necessary, simply state `start "" /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\HotSpot 3.0.3" [/WAIT] "Hotspot303.exe"` (the `[]` mean optional)...

Comment: I fixed the issues. First, the double quotes fixed some stuff. But mainly my issue was not resetting file as Current.hot after each iteration. The code didn't know what to access after the second iteration. Thanks everyone for the help!